# Raid Issues Cannot Boot and Getting Superblock Errors

Tags: server, mount, raid, mdadm

I am getting the errors below. How do I get the RAID array fixed. I'd like to get it mounted via the live cd that im booted into as well. Just so I can backup a few items. My setup boots from the RAID array so I'm dead in the water without it.

```
root@ubuntu:~# mount /dev/md1 /mnt/
mount: /dev/md1: can't read superblock

root@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md1 : inactive sdf2[7](S) sda1[8](S) sdg1[6](S) sde2[4](S) sdd2[11](S) sdc2[9](S) sdb2[1](S)
      10142801446 blocks super 1.2

md0 : active raid6 sdf1[6] sdg2[7] sde1[4] sdb1[1]
      62490624 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/4] [UU__UU]

unused devices: 

root@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu# mdadm --examine --scan

ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=c8081091:2f4943d7:10dec27a:157f4bc1 name=ubuntu-server:0

ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=42cc1f4f:4e4936d6:7459207c:9d4b12e8 name=ubuntu-server:1

root@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu# mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: /dev/sdh2 has wrong uuid
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdh
mdadm: /dev/sdf2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf
mdadm: /dev/sdg2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdg
mdadm: /dev/sdd2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdc2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sde2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/sdb2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sda1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: /dev/md/0 is already in use.
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md/1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/md/0
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdj
mdadm: cannot open device /dev/sr0: No medium found
mdadm: /dev/sdh1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdh
mdadm: /dev/sdf2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdf
mdadm: /dev/sdg2 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: /dev/sdg1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdg
mdadm: /dev/sdd2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdd
mdadm: /dev/sdc2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdc
mdadm: /dev/sde2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sde
mdadm: /dev/sdb2 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has wrong uuid.
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sda1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/sda
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop1
mdadm: no RAID superblock on /dev/loop0
mdadm: /dev/md/1 is already in use.

Disk /dev/sda: 1999.8 GB, 1999844147200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243133 cylinders, total 3905945600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ab645

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63  2897949284  1448974611   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a3189

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sde: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0006f679

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sde2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000ec83c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdc2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0002c199

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdd2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdg: 1999.8 GB, 1999844147200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243133 cylinders, total 3905945600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005f94c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdg1              63  2897949284  1448974611   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdg2      2897949285  2929195709    15623212+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdf: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0005da7c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdf1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdf2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdh: 1499.7 GB, 1499748892672 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182334 cylinders, total 2929197056 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a2f98

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdh1            2048    31250431    15624192   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdh2   *    31250432  2929195007  1448972288   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdj: 16.0 GB, 16005464064 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1945 cylinders, total 31260672 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdj1   *           2    31260671    15630335    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/md0: 64.0 GB, 63990398976 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 15622656 cylinders, total 124981248 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 524288 bytes / 2097152 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

I was able to get it to reassemble with

oot@ubuntu:~# mdadm --assemble --force /dev/md1 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2 /dev/sdd2 /dev/sde2 /dev/sdf2 /dev/sdg1 /dev/sdh2

Then I ran

mdadm --add for the drives that were missing. its rebuilding now. we will see if after all is said and done if it will boot.I do have it mounted now so I can grab some data.

Comment: What's the question you're asking?